# Замена только одного слова из нескольких в поле БД

Tags: mysql

Привет!

Нашёл в сети команду MySQL:

```
UPDATE `tablitsa` SET `pole` = REPLACE( pole, 'А', 'Б' )
```

То есть если я задам заменить "А" на "Б", то в поле все слова "А" будут заменены на "Б". А мне нужно заменить только первое встречающееся слово в поле на заданное, а последующие не трогать. Долго читал мануал мускуля, но так и не нашёл ответа.
Как это сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте ORDER BY (?) LIMIT 1

> UPDATE `tablitsa` SET `pole` = REPLACE( pole, 'А', 'Б' ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Похожая проблема и решение на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220572)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но я понял, что написал свой вопрос не до конца. 
Команда выше заменит одно значение в одном поле и прекратится?
А мне нужно, чтобы поменялись значения всех полей в таблице (по одному слову в каждом), или заданное число полей.

Comment: @Ариан да, команда выше затронет только одну строку. Самый простой (и возможно эффективный) подход - повторить эту операцию для каждого поля, которое нужно изменить. Если мы укажем несколько полей, то все они будут обновлены, по этой причине я не вижу других  возможных решений